# reserving all processor resources, Core and Cache

Tags: c#, java, c++, multithreading, caching

I'm a CS student working on Learning algorithms on my own. The algorithm I'm working on now will have to run about two months on a powerful PC to yeild anything useful, so processor efficiency makes a big difference. The majority of processor time will be spent running one sub-process with different initial values.

Ideally I'd like to run several of these sub-processes on separate threads, reserve one core and part of the cache per thread for about an hour. After that hour I can allow time for the OS to run other processes, and check for user input. As soon as that's finished I'd like to reserve all the resources again for an hour.

Is there a simple way to do this, if not is it even worth doing (5%-10% increase in performance is worth doubling programming time), if it's worth doing but will be difficult what resources are there for figuring it out?

I'm familiar with C++ JAVA and could do C# if neccessary

Comment: What's your target OS? Given an otherwise quiescent machine, the improvement from doing this is likely to be well under 1%.

Comment: Are you sure, to ask for all of these languages in a single question?? That's blatantly too broad: c#, java and c++ are very different, and there are various techniques to handle multi-threading for each of them.

Answer (score 3):

There is no modern CPU where cache is controlled by user-mode software, and even if this was not the case, you will have no luck whatsoever with IMPROVING the performance by trying to "disable cache when entering the OS" or similar ideas.

Similarly, aside from perhaps using processor affinity for each process/thread, there is no meaningful point in "locking CPU resources".

The overhead of the OS is minimal in a modern system, as long as the system isn't running `xgears` or something similar as a "screensaver". Turn that off, and you should get 99.9% of the CPU-performance for your application.

If you want more performance out of the system, you are MUCH better looking at the code generated by the compiler, choosing algorithms that are efficient for your problem, etc. Obviously, use a profiler to identify the "hot spots" of your application.

Answer (score 2):

While there are ways to set the priority of running thread to "high", perhaps you should consider a different overall strategy. Your problem description implies that you will have multiple independent calculations to make ("one sub-process with different initial values").  Perhaps you should consider breaking the calculation into the "sub work units", storing initial values and results in a database ... and recruit other students to run these sub work units during free time on their computers.

For the computer that you use, do try making multiple threads (many laptops have the equivalent of 8 CPUs via multi-core and hyperthreading).

Answer (score 1):

The question is ambiguous. Let me explain some options with respect to speeding up the code as your primary concern seems to that.

1. If you have multicore processor use parallel programming come with C# 4.0 or use MPI or OpenMP
2. There are many parallelization technique which you can use to increase your processing speed like tiling etc depends on the problem
3. Make sure each thread or process are independent like making your log file separated etc so that each thread can run by its own.
4. Make sure all your threads have high priority
5. Make your program 64 bit application if you have more than 4GB of memory
6. Increase your system clock cycles
7. Increase your RAM memory for the process (e.g if yo u have 4GB not all 4GB is used by process there should be options to control that depending on your operating system.
8. If you know of any process like anti-virus use http://www.maketecheasier.com/limit-app-cpu-usage-in-windows/ this to limit their cpu access
9. Use cache-analysis and try to improve your code.
10. There are some supercomputing centers, if you need more power reach out to them and ask for cluster nodes - you may get lucky !